# ServiceStack Authentication validation with Captcha

Tags: c#, servicestack

I want to put a CAPTCHA field into the the auth submit form `api/auth/credentials`.

So, now the form will need to contain a **captcha** field apart from **username**, **password** and **rememberme**.

I will then check the session where I stored the answer of the captcha image vs the form submitted captcha result.

My question is, which part(s) of the SS source code do I need to override in order to do it correctly?

My feeling is that I should look into override and customise CredentialsAuthProvider class for the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quickie way to do it:

```
    public ExtDeskResponse Post(MyAuth req) {
        //Captcha Validation
        var valid = req.Captcha == base.Session.Get<Captcha>("Captcha").result;
        //SS Authentication
        var authService = AppHostBase.Instance.TryResolve<AuthService>();
        authService.RequestContext = new HttpRequestContext(
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ToRequest(),
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ToResponse(),
            null);
        var auth = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
            authService.Authenticate(new Auth {
                UserName = req.UserName,
                Password = req.Password,
                RememberMe = req.RememberMe,   
            }).UserName);
        if (valid && auth) { 
            //...logic
        }
        return new MyAuthResponse() {
            //...data
        }; 
    }
```

Look forward to see you guys show me more elegant/efficient/expandable ways to do it.